# Read a physically partitioned data using wildcards

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a persisted dataframe on AWS S3 with the following structure:

```
s3://bucket/df/
|__ date=2020-02-19/
    |__ FILENAME01.json
    |__ FILENAME02.json
    |__ FILENAME03
    |__ ...
|__ date=2020-02-20/
    |__ FILENAME04.json
    |__ FILENAME05
    |__ ...
|__ ...
```

If I read this dataframe using the following syntax:

```
df = spark.read.json("s3://bucket/df)"
```

The file that doesn't have extensions will be part of my dataframe and this is not desirable. So, I would like to only consider the files with `.json` extension.

So I decided to read this dataframe filtering the files with suffix `*.json`. In a practical way, I tried the following:

```
df = spark.read.json("s3://bucket/df/date=*/*.json")
```

The `spark.read.json` worked, but the column `date` used to partition my dataframe wasn't present. Is there any way to retrieve only files that match to a specific suffix inside partition folders, without losing the partition column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark can only discover partitions under the given input path. But here your path contains already the partition `date`. You can read this from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery) :

> Starting from Spark 1.6.0, partition discovery only finds partitions
> under the given paths by default. For the above example, if users pass
> `path/to/table/gender=male` to either `SparkSession.read.parquet` or
> `SparkSession.read.load`, gender will not be considered as a
> partitioning column. If users need to specify the base path that
> partition discovery should start with, they can set basePath in the
> data source options. For example, when `path/to/table/gender=male` is
> the path of the data and users set basePath to `path/to/table/`, gender
> will be a partitioning column.

You can specify the `basePath` option :

```
df = spark.read.option("basePath", "s3://bucket/df/").json("s3://bucket/df/date=*/*.json")
```

Or alternatively, you can extract back the `date` partition from the `input_file_name` using `regexp_extract` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "date",
    F.regexp_extract(F.input_file_name(), r".*/date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/.*", 1)
)
```